# Angular not compatible with chrome

Tags: angular5

I have a dropdown list with two links in angular. it is working with firefox and not working with chrome. is there any compatible issues for angular with chrome?

```
<div id="SelectField">
   <select class="form-control form-control-lg">
     <option value="" selected disabled>Select to Deploy Product/Products</option>
     <option (click)="Single()">Deploy Single Product</option>
     <option (click)="Multiple()">Deploy Multiple Products</option>
   </select>      
 </div>
```

It is working fine with firefox but in chrome its not activating when we select an option

Answer (score 0):

You can use change event in select tag and set the value of first option as undefined and rest of the options with any string value inside [ngValue]="single".

Here single is a string value which is assigned to that option.
You have to check in the change event with if condition what is passed as a value based on that you can call your respective methods..

Make sure you have to use ngModel in the select and ngValue will be your selected option value